# A plant in my aquarium seems to be growing small plants under its leaves, what's going on?

Tags: botany, parasitology, aquaculture

In my aquarium I have this plant. I think it's a kind of swordplant. I've loosely attached it to a large piece of driftwood in the hope that it will grow itself on there, I saw that they had done the same in the petstore.

Now recently other plants have started to grow from under its leaves. I've tried to take a picture of it, these are the biggest ones but there are smaller ones on other leaves: [image]

The plant seems to be doing pretty well, I added some iron and fertiliser to the water. The aquarium is positioned so that it catches a bit of direct sunlight late in the day and tons of indirect sunlight almost all day. It also houses shrimps and two apple snails.

My question: What are these small leaves? Is the plant procreating or does are these some kind of parasitical plants of another species?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see ,it does look like some kind of Echinodorus ( Amazon sword). They do propagate by stems with new plants. They prefer to have roots in substrate.

Comment: Yeah I agree it looks like some sort of Amazon Sword, but I also know that grows stems with plants and that's not what I see here, so I'm still wondering what these are.

Comment: Java fern has new little plants that start from the leaves but  the photo does not show enough for identification. I have a bunch of java fern and it does not need substrate.

Comment: I looked up some more pictures of Java Fern propagating, that is for sure what this is, thanks! Crazy, I never knew this. Will try to get them to grow into mature plants:)